# 18.04 on thinkpad T480s : no automatic wifi reconnection when autoconnect to vpn is turned on

Tags: wireless, network-manager, vpn, thinkpad, connection

Using `nm-connection-editor` I was able to ask my laptop to automatically connect to a vpn when connecting to my home network.

Unfortunately, when this option is activated my computer does not automatically connect to the WIFIs, disabling the option immediately restores the normal behavior.

I tested this with several VPNs as well as several different WIFIs.

Does anybody know how I could fix this ?

Thanks a lot !